# Stack and Heap?

Tags: c++, variables, heap-memory

i didn't understand something about stack in functions for variables,if a process is given a heap isn't the stack inside that heap or when people compare heap and stack they mean instead heap a heap block that created from allocation?.And when a pointer in function pointing to allocated structure what does it mean in this situation?

Comment: The stack is not inside the heap.  At least not in Windows or Linux.

Comment: @JohnDibling can you explain?

Comment: @user1779374: Each process has global memory, thread local memory, executable memory, one or more heaps, one or more stacks, and probably other stuff.  They're all seperate.